# Regex to check if user id is valid using condition

Tags: regex

I am new to `regex` and have a requirement to check if the userId entered is correct or not using `regex`.

Requirement:

1. Must have 1 to 4 characters at start
2. Must have 1 to 4 numbers at end.

ex:

valid: `A1`, `AB12`, `ABCD123`, `ABCD1234`

invalid: `123`, `ABC`, `ABCD12345`, `ABCDE123`

i tried using `/^([(a-zA-Z)]{0,4})([0-9]{0,5})$/g` but all cases does not pass.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEch6k/1/)

Comment: Thanks @dawg, i should have done `{1,4}` instead of `{0,4}`.

Comment: * i should have done {1,4} instead of {0,4}* -- correct